Strange Insufficient Allowance Error where the contract owns the tokens?

cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: Insufficient Allowance", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x9080Cd8c6964a5c3b0735839AEE841a1D91F2a79","to":"0x05A333fAaEE694cB591A456e3BE8F83157464F4c","data":"0x608e4dd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted: Insufficient Allowance","data":"0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016496e73756666696369656e7420416c6c6f77616e636500000000000000000000","cause":null}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT,

    function unstakeTokens(uint256 _stakeId) public payable nonReentrant() BNBFeeEnabled() {
    require(stakeId[_stakeId].listingAddress == msg.sender, "!Ownership");
    require(stakeId[_stakeId].enabled == true, "!Enabled");

    uint256 stakeReward = getStakeRewards(_stakeId);
    IERC20 tokenContract;
    tokenContract = IERC20(stakeId[_stakeId].tokenAddress);

    stakeId[_stakeId].enabled = false; 

    tokenContract.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, stakeId[_stakeId].tokenAmount);
    MSFY.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, stakeReward);

    activeStakes = activeStakes - 1;    
    userStakingManifest[msg.sender].remove(_stakeId);  
    userTotalStakes[msg.sender] = userTotalStakes[msg.sender].sub(1);
    userTokenManifest[msg.sender][stakeId[_stakeId].tokenAddress] = false;
    if (pricingEnabled == true)   {
        (bool success , ) = feeCollector.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    }
}

I Have tried :

Disabling the BNBFee but any fee in bnb should not need any allowance.
Tried setting the Gas .... The Result the transaction actually starts up but then fails

Is there a way to determine which token is expecting the allowance ?

where you able to solve the problem?

You are using the wrong function. To transfer the tokens use
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
and not the transferFrom function that you are currently using.


transfer is used by the token owner to move tokens directly from their account.
transferFrom is used by a third party who has been authorized by the token owner (via approve) to move tokens on behalf of the owner.


I see these guys did an override and even the transfer function is directed at their transferFrom function. Should i just add an approval to the staking contract ? As that is the contract i can change
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external override returns (bool)    {         uint256 senderBalance = _balances[msg.sender];         require(senderBalance >= value, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");         _transferFrom(msg.sender, to, value);         return true;     } 

if the contract owns the tokens, and the contract is sending the tokens from itself then transfer needs to be used. safeTransferFrom won't work because the contract would need to call the approve method for itself to spend it's own tokens using that function.

the override is just because it's overriding the interface method from IERC20 probably.

just by reading the error
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
every action in the blockchain is a transaction and every transaction requires computational work and for that end you need to pay a fee in the blockchain native currency, in this case BNB. you cannot possibly disable the BNB fee.
But try this in the js file that you are sending the transaction pass the gas limit as so.
 let tx = await contract.functionName(params,{gasLimit : 300000});
//make sure to pass the gas limit as an obj
                                                

you can play with the gass limit,but 300k gwei should work
hope it helps!
